# Why is ArcMap editor deleting some added vertices and simplifying polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, editing, vertices

I am using ArcMap 10.0. I am trying to edit (and add) vertices in a polygon.

I start editing, (using "Edit Vertices" tool), and add many vertices in the polygon.

Then when I am done, I save the changes. But, the image gets simplified and I lose many of the additions!

Why is the editor deleting some vertices and simplifying the polygon?

Comment: When you say "save the changes" do you mean Finish Sketch or have you jumped straight to Save Edits?

Comment: Either. I believe I have tried both.

Comment: @P auritus, what type of layer are you editing (shapefile, geodatabase feature class)?  Do you have any topology rules set?

Comment: What coordinate system (spatial ref) is the data frame in, and what is the layer's? It sounds like the xy tolerance or resolution of the data layer may be too big compared to how close together you're trying to place the new vertices.

Comment: Do you have large snapping tolerances set?

Comment: I am having the same issue with new vertices being deleted and/or polygons being simplified. The XY tolerance and resolution are in balance. The georeferencing tool is not open. The only thing that has changed recently is we are using an ArcSDE geodatabase. Also, when using the identify tool and selecting a polygon, it selects everything nearby, not just the layers at the point that is selected. Seems like some sort of tolerance issue with my settings. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I believe mkennedy nailed it. If your polygons are being simplified, try drawing a much larger one. If that is successful, it means some of the vertexes in your smaller polygons are too close together because of data frame/layer coordinate system mismatch, and they are being snapped.

Answer (score 3):

I am a GIS trainer in France and this problem happened to one of my students. The file he was editing on (process of georeferencing before) was not correct and the georeferencing tool was still open when the problem occurred. When referencing the image properly and closing the georef tool before editing the problem didn't appear anymore.