# Morphing Polygons using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, polygon, editing

We recently migrated from ArcMap 9.3 to 10.6.1. Since migrating we are experiencing issues with polygons changing after we hit finish sketch. This usually happens when there are curves or indents present.

I found [Why is ArcMap editor deleting some added vertices and simplifying polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/43440/115) and was wondering if any of the answers solved the user's problem.

I am new to ArcMap.

---

We had our consultant's take a look and here is what they said they did, which seems to have mostly fixed the issue (for now): "I grouped all of the feature classes together and copied them from the original data frame to a new one in the same mxd. This kept them in the same drawing order. The new data frame was set to use a reference scale of 1:1500 and the maps table was added to the mxd (as user cmaccarthy). The maps table was rejoined to the data driven page feature class. The original data frame was removed which also removed the north arrow and the scale bar from the layout. A new north arrow and scale bar was added to the new data frame."  Does this make sense to any of you seasoned ArcMap users?  I'm still trying to understand what was wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: The OP in the question you linked never accepted either of the answers, so it's hard to say whether their issue was solved.

Comment: Thanks lambertj.  Maybe I should re-phrase the question.  The point of the post is to get an answer to this question, not really to find out if the OP's issue was solved.

Comment: Make sure each featureclass and your dataFrame has a defined Coordinate System, otherwise the default XY Tolerance & Resolution might be too large, resulting in snapping issues.

Comment: To determine if either/both of the answers to the duplicate question are useful to you, I think you should try them. If they are, then vote on them according to what your rep permits. If not, then you could describe in detail here the steps you took to try to use them, and where you got stuck. That could lead to re-opening of your question.